# ASP.NET ChangePassword control with ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, asp.net-membership

I have a webapp that uses Forms Authentication using ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.
That works fine... users can do login successfully.

Once the user do login, he can change the password.
We use a ChangePassword control that retrieve the Membership information and uses the OLD and new password to change the user's password.  **THAT Doesn't work**.

The Exception message thrown is that the password doesn't fits the password policies (Not the message of the provider, but the underlying COM object. But this is not the case, as going to the ActiveDirectory console and changing the password there do works. When using the ActiveDirectory console we used a quite simple password: "Password01".

The user in ActiveDirectory is set to Allow changing password. All our users are stored in a certain OU and the connection string to AD points to this OU also. Again, the connection is successfull as we can do Login.

**Any other thing that can prevent us to change Password?**

*Exception information*

```
    System.Web.Security.MembershipPasswordException: The password supplied is invalid.
Passwords must conform to the password strength requirements configured for the default provider.
---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800708C5): The password does not meet the password policy requirements. Check the minimum password length, password complexity and password history requirements. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800708C5)
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.ChangePassword(String username, String oldPassword, String newPassword)
       at System.Web.Security.MembershipUser.ChangePassword(String oldPassword, String newPassword)
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact COM exception information (also from the innerException that may be there)?

Comment: There I added the Exception thrown. The password entered by me in my tests was really complex... so I don't think the message is accurate. Thanks for looking at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, sorry for the inconvenience...

The problem was that the Active Directory Administrator had set that you can **wait a day** before changing the password.

So, if we create a user... the USER must wait 1 day to change his password.
The Administrator can reset a password without this restriction.

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1):

When you configure the membership provider in the web.config there are several password related values that can be set, namely:

```
MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters
MinRequiredPasswordLength
PasswordStrengthRegularExpression
```

I would first make sure that all of these are set to values which will match up with ActiveDirectory.

Next, make sure that the connectionProtection attribute is set to SignAndSeal, you cannot change passwords otherwise:

```
connectionProtection="SignAndSeal"
```

Besides those suggestions, I looked in Reflector and all the COM errors (except 0x7FF8FAD2) are being thrown straight up to the client.  Error 0x800708C5 appears in the MSDN in several places but always with the text that password complexity is not sufficient.

Comment: Is this for a specific verison, when i add this it shows as and invalid setting for "Sign and Seal"